# Cheap modern image editor to stitch images, draw basic shapes, crop, resize

Tags: windows, vector-graphics, image-processing, image-editor

I need graphics software to edit images.
The requirements I'm interested in are:

- very cheap license (< $25, free, or trial-usable forever)
- not very old DLL dependency (VB6 or similar)
- not very old UI (remember windows 3.11 software? I don't want something similar and ugly)
- can "stitch" images together
- can crop, resize, or otherwise change paper size
- **supports drawing lines, circles, squares on the image** (very important)
- Filters are not needed: marquees, layer and image adjustment are really more important
- Vector graphic support would be an interesting add-on

You can refer to PicPick Editor as an example. It's similar to what I want but it's missing resize, canvas resize and image stitch.

The platform which I need it for is **Windows**.

**GIMP** is not a solution because I couldn't draw circles easily on the image. The learning curve seems steeper. It is more oriented on photographic retouch.

Comment: Related [meta question](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/436/whats-wrong-with-question-like-this/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy-to-use cross-platform photograph retouching tool?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/114/easy-to-use-cross-platform-photograph-retouching-tool)

Comment: Easy stiching to create collage of different pictures or easy stiching to create scenes similar to panoramas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/). It is a free image editing software. It is easy to handle as MS Paint, but contains a lot of advanced features. It supports many different formats. I use it very often to edit images. It is easy to handle and available with translations for different languages. 
Paint.NET:

- is free
- has a modern interface
- supports painting on the image
- is able to change the size of the paper, the image and crop the image
- has vector graphic support, made possible via a plugin
- makes it possible to stitch images together [How to stitch images in Paint.NET](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/4602-stitching-photos/)
- has support for add-ons

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I've downloaded it. It seems to me better than Pinta as graphic interface and they seem to allow for the same things to be done. Have you tried the other one? Do you know also some cheap software (not only freeware) better than Paint .NET? Pinta also requires for external libraries to be installed.

Comment: Which one I have tried? I use several image software (IrfanView, Inkscape) for viewing and editing. So for small things Paint.NET was always enough for me. Gimp is to complex for me. I know that there is [Photgraphix](http://lmadhavan.com/software/fotografix/). But I never tried it. So I don't know if it is better than Paint.NET.

Comment: I just know Adobe Photoshop, Visio, Corel Suite, Acdsee and now Paint.NET. I would like something more than Paint.Net. Now I'm going to try also Gimp. What about IrfanView, Inkscape?

Comment: Visio is good for technical drawings, so I used it for that. Corel and ACDsee I've never really use and Photoshop is too complex. IrfanView is a small all in one graphics viewer. If you prefer an answer with IrfanView I can post one, because I cannot explain it here in a comment. But it doesn't fulfill your requirements, because it is a viewer with some editing functions like draw lines, circles and so on. Inkscape is a vector graphics drawing software. So for drawing and not really for image manipulating.

Comment: I will try to open a question askying just for IrfanView

Answer (score 6):

**[PicPick](http://www.picpick.org/)** is an image editor available for Windows.

- It has a free licence for personal use, or commercial licence available (currently US$25).
- It has a reasonably modern interface in that it has a context sensitive "ribbon bar".
- It supports canvas cropping and resizing
- It supports selection resizing
- It supports manual image stitching in that you can enlarge the canvas and paste another image in the new area.
- It supports rudimentary drawing (pencil, brush, lines, shapes, etc).
- Once created these shapes can be edited like vectors, but will they be need to be flattened when performing a raster operation.

[image]

Note that  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> will resize the canvas while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> will resize selection.  These are also available on the ribbon bar in the Image section.

WARNING: The installer for the free version will offer to install some unrelated products (currently a youtube downloader and a registry cleaner), it is possible to opt out.

Comment: `youtube downloader and a registry cleaner` No malware? Lucky.